# What is the values of the $P(a)$ and $P(b)$ here?

Tags: probability, expectation-maximization

I am watching a video on EM algorithm [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQoXFmbXRJA&index=2&list=PLBv09BD7ez_4e9LtmK626Evn1ion6ynrt).

It gives an example of how EM algorithm works. At first two Gaussian distributions are randomly given, and then by iterative calculations their parameters converge to specific values. As shown in the following picture, my question is what's the values of $P(a)$ and $P(b)$? Are they predefined? (the red circles).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the prior distribution of the two classes (a=yellow and b=blue). I thought I heard him mention in the video he is using equal priors: $P(a) = P(b) = 1/2$.